# I want to display the quantity of the selected item of a drop down list in a textbox

Tags: jsp, servlets

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showconfirm() {
    var a = confirm("Do you want to Buy ?");    
    if(a == true) {
        alert("Book is Yours!");
    } else {
        alert("Paisa nahi hai toh aage bado!!");
    }
}
</script>
```

my problem is the price and quantity of last item in the database is getting populated into the textbox. This shouldn't be the case. Quantity and price should change everytime I select a new item.

```
<table align = 'center' cellspacing='15' style = "background-color:brown" >
    <tr>    

      <%
       try {
          data = new MysqlDataSource();
          con =  data.getConnection("root","system");
          System.out.println("Connected to MySQL"); 
          PreparedStatement pre = con.prepareStatement("select * from library.booklist");
          result = pre.executeQuery();       
      %> 

        <td> <i> Book List : </i></td> 
         <td> <select name= "BookList" id="Booklist" > 
              <option> - select - </option>
    <%  
    while (result.next())  
    {
           name = result.getString("Book"); 

    %>
    <option value="<%=name%>"> <%=name%></option>

    <% 
    }
}
catch (SQLException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
    %>
</select>
</td>
</tr>

    <tr>
       <%
    try {
     ItemNames [] = request.getParameterValues("BookList");
     System.out.println(ItemNames);
     pre = con.prepareStatement("select Quantity from library.booklist where Book = ? ");  
     pre.setString(1,ItemNames); 
      result = pre.executeQuery();
      %>
     <td><i> Quantity : </i>  </td>
  <%
    while (result.next())  
    {
       int show = result.getInt("Quantity"); 
  %>
<td> <input name = "Quantity" id = "Quantity" type = "text" size = "10" readonly = "readonly" value = "<%=show%>"> </td>
   <%
   }
   } 
    catch (SQLException e1) 
    {
    e1.printStackTrace();
    }

   %>
   </tr>



     <tr> 
    <%
    try {
     pre = con.prepareStatement("select Price from library.booklist where Book = ? ");  
     pre.setString(1,name); 
      result = pre.executeQuery();
      %>

      <td><i> Price : </i>  </td> 
   <%
    while (result.next())  
    {
       double mrp = result.getDouble("Price"); 
   %>

<td> <input name = "Price" id = "Price" type = "text" size = "10" readonly = "readonly" value = "<%=mrp%>">  </td>
   <%
   }
   } 
    catch (SQLException e1) 
    {
    e1.printStackTrace();
    }  
   %>
     </tr> 

    <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td><input label='Submit' value='Buy' type='Submit'  onclick = 'showconfirm()' value ='Showconfirmbox' /> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to display price and quantity into a textbox on selecting any item from drop down list. The data is stored in Database. How to get selected data from list in jsp?

Comment: Please don’t write `== true`. It’s redundant.

Comment: Using database access in JSP is antipattern. Search MVC.

Comment: Don't use scriplets. Instead use EL, JSTL.

Answer (score 0):

> Quantity and price should change everytime I select a new item.

Javascript and Ajax.  If you want something to happen when the user does something on the interface, you have to use Javascript.  Because only Javascript can respond to client-side events.

> How to get selected data from list in jsp?

In this code you are building the page to send to the client.  Obviously since the client has not seen the page yet, they haven't selected anything.